# How to add attributes to elements when making request with SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need to make a SOAP call and a request shoul look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="xxxxxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:getOptions>
         <arg0 username="?" password="?">
            <getOptionsBusinessData/>
         </arg0>
      </soap:getOptions>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is that possible with PHP SoapClient?

Tried many things all of which resulted in java nullpoint exception. Now I'm trying

```
    $xml_string = '<getOptions>
    <arg0 username="xxxx" password="xxxx">
    <getOptionsBusinessData/>
    </arg0>
    </getOptions>';

    $client = new \SoapClient('https://example.com?wsdl');

    $args = array(new \SoapVar($xml_string, XSD_ANYXML));
    $res  = $client->__soapCall('getOptions', $args);
    return $res;
```

Got different kind of error `SoapFault Cannot find dispatch method for {}getOptions`. I'm stuck! How do I unstuck?

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass xml string as parameter. SoapClient is supposed to generate the XML for you. Try following call:

```
$client = new \SoapClient('https://example.com?wsdl');
$res = $client->getOptions(array('username' => 'xxx', 'password' => 'xxx'));
return $res;
```

Comment: It returns `SoapFault java.lang.NullPointerException`. According to docs `getOptions` method accepts `GetOptionsSoapRequest` which looks like xml in example. I imagine passing this array would construct `<username>xxx</username><password>xxx</password>`
Besides, I'm not passing a string. I'm passing SoapVar object constructed from string :)